# Cassandra data model for time series data to query last hour data

Tags: database, cassandra, time-series, bigdata, data-modeling

I have a scenario to save events from devices which will trigger in 30 seconds interval. A single event will consists of maximum 20 fields (no of columns in the table will be 20) and I need to run a query to fetch last hour events from the table to do batch process. Since it's a time series data, as per my knowledge I don't think it's a best practice to choose hour as partition key because as the number of devices increase it will end up huge partition. So if I choose year or month as partition key to control the partition size, how will I fetch the last hour events?

1, Is it good option to choose Cassandra in this situation or is there any better option ?

2, If I choose Cassandra how should I design the data model to handle the situation?

- Open for possibilities

Answer (score 0):

Yes Cassandra is the best choice.

We should always design the Cassandra table for a query.
I would design the table as below -

```
CREATE TABLE DEVICE_EVENT_BY_HOUR (
year int,
month int,
week int,
day int,
hour int,
value text,
PRIMARY KEY ((year, month, week, day, hour),value);

The value column will have all the event values in json format.
```

This will evenly distribute the events across the cluster. Only problem with this design is, if we have too many updates in one particular hour of the day, it will flood that partition.